# How can I get "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified" to output the specification?

Tags: python, file, runtime-error

The error message `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` doesn't display the file specification.

How can I get it to display the file specification?

I understand that, in some cases, this might be difficult to automate, but given that it is frequently the case that errors like this hit users of software, rather than developers, and that it is also frequently the case that the file was opened with a pathname, it seems reasonable to expect this error message to make a best attempt.  So it also seems reasonable to expect that there would be a straight-forward configuration of Python, or at least a simple modification to application-level global error handling, to make the attempt.

Comment: look up python `try` and `except` statements.

Comment: Can you show an example of the context in which you get that error?

Comment: That answer is appropriate for developers of the software raising the exception, not the users of the software even if they are developing software that uses the software raising the exception.